# Create Sparkmagic spark session on Ipython kernel

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I started working with SparkMagic lately, I was able to create notebooks on PySpark kernel which works fine.
Now when I use SparkMagic on Ipython kernel, there's a step which should be done manually (execute %manage_spark, create endpoint, create session)
[image]

I would like to know if there's away to do these steps programatically!